# open source text to speech library

Tags: c, open-source, text-to-speech

Does any one know of a good text to speech library. It needs to be open source and provide C   API?

PS: I've already done a search, but I'd like recommendations from people who have actually used these APIs

Comment: See page intended for this purpose: https://www.slant.co/improve/topics/4456/~open-source-text-to-speech-tts-engines

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can go for [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival) worked nice for me.

Comment: Festival is the devil.  Took me all day to get it installed on OS X and to try out different voices.  All the voices are really crappy quality.  Sucks.

Answer (score 19):

[Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) is an open source text-to-speech system.

Stanford uses it for their Natural Language Processing class, and they have up-to-date instructions about installation on this [cs224s homework page](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224s/hw/).  Installation on Mac OS X requires a couple patches, which they've wrapped into a handy [install script](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs224s/festival_mac/install_festival.py).

There are alternate voices you can use which sound *noticeably* better than the stock ones.  You can find information on these voices in this forum post:
[How to setup more realistic voices in Festival](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=677277).  Those instructions are for Ubuntu, but the voices work with any Festival installation.

Comment: oh man that link you've provided is just ASTONISHING!!!!! it's such a realistic voice listen to this!! http://festvox.org/ldom/ldom_com.html

Comment: They do sound great, but I'm clueless as to how to use them. I'm trying to use Flite for iOS

Comment: wow @holms! nice linkage! that sample totally rocks!

Answer (score 9):

I have used [flite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/) in an embedded server. It has a small footprint and comes with a single voice

Answer (score 7):

[eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) is another lightweight TTS. More robotty than Festival.

Answer (score 2):

Hey what about [MARY](http://mary.dfki.de)? 
It looks so awesome to me which one should we push further for open source enterprise computer or androids or whatever? We need to strenghten efforts by shifting all open source resources to the best/most promising we have so far.

Anyone experiences with MARY TTS? Or does it have a flaw (because noone mentioned it before)?
More links:

http://www.babelfish.org/tts-free.htm.
https://www.cereproc.com/en/support/live_demo
http://www.digitalfuturesoft.com/dfttssdk.php (also provides ARM version, like MARY + Festival)