# Find a simple speech engine

Tags: c++, audio, c++builder, text-to-speech

I'm doing a project on text recognition. One of the main points here is text-to-speech translation after the recognition. Could you help me find a very **simple**, plain speech engine for **C++ Builder project**? All that I've found were not only very complicated, but also they were suitable for MFC.

So, the problem is that I'd like to convert **text to speech**. No recognizing, just simple convertion. Please share some info about this problem, maybe I should look it up somewhere?

Basically, I do not even know, if I'm calling it right, so I'm sorry for misunderstanding if it happens.

Comment: Have a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637616/open-source-text-to-speech-library

Comment: Well thanks. It helped a bit, though this is not what I expexted(some simple class, or a library). If anyone knows something else, it'd be fantastic.

Comment: Ive never used borland, but in MSVC2010, I have used [the native api SAPI before](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720151(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you, hope it won't be very difficult to use it with Borland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's Speech API (SAPI) is implemented as a set of COM objects, and thus is usable in C++Builder projects with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

[Flite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/) is a small text to speech engine written in portable C, with no specific OS dependencies and with a permissive open source license. You will need to create a C++ Builder project to build it, but other than that it should work just fine.