# Which Text To Speech should i use in iOS?

Tags: ios

Now i am confusing about Text To Speech Engine for iOS.

When i search in internet, i found two kinds of Text To Speech Engine for iOS.

These are iSpeech and Dragon Mobile SDK from Nuance.

i have to use Text To Speech for multiple languages and also have to use Speech To Text.

I want to know which engine is better and which is faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also explore c libs like discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637616/open-source-text-to-speech-library and port them